# Is $\cos x$ irreducible as a power series?

Tags: complex-analysis, ring-theory, power-series, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\mathbb{Q}_{\mathrm{ent}}[[x]]$ be the ring of entire functions with rational coefficients.  Is 
$$
\cos x \;=\; \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\!\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n)!}
$$
irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}_\mathrm{ent}[[x]]$?

Comment: By an entire function, I mean a power series with infinite radius of convergence, i.e. a power series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ for which $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty} \sqrt[n]{a_n} = 0$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have the trigonometric identity

$$\cos x = \cos^2 \frac{x}{2} - \sin^2 \frac{x}{2} = \left(\cos \frac{x}{2} - \sin \frac{x}{2}\right)\left(\cos\frac{x}{2} + \sin \frac{x}{2}\right),$$

and both factors are entire power series with rational coefficients, and not units, since they have zeros in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Ah, of course.  Thanks!